# APA in-text citations are cut short (e.g. 020a instead of 2020a)

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, apa-style, apacite

Instead of the in-text citation appearing as (SCALER, 2020a), it appears as (SCALER, 020a). Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

For the in-text reference, I'm using \citep{scaler_business_2020}.

This is the bib reference:

```
@techreport{scaler_business_2020,
    title = {Business case framework},
    HowPublished={\url{https://www.scalerproject.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/D4.3_SCALER_BUSINESS_CASE_FRAMEWORK_v1.0.pdf}},
    Note = {[Accessed: 19.08.2023]},
    author = {{SCALER}},
    year = {2020a},
}
```

These commands are in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

This is what I use to generate the reference section (where the publication date is displayed correctly):

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

Comment: you should make a complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue. But my first try would be to remove the `a` from the year.

Answer (score 2):

The first mistake you've made is to execute two `\bibliographystyle` directives in one document: BibTeX ignores all but the first one of them. Now, where you were truly *unlucky* is that your first-named bib style -- `apalike` -- happens not to be that set up properly for handling anything but four-digit numerical-format `year` fields.

Had you not specified `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` -- please note that, incidentally, the `apacite` citation management package should only ever be used together with the `apacite` bibliography style -- you would not have encountered this particular issue.

In a broader sense, though, it can never be correct to hard-code a letter such as `a` into the `year` field. For if you do that, you'll be stuck with that suffix letter even if your bibliography contains one and only one entry published by `SCALER` in 2020. Do let BibTeX handle the letter suffix insertion business for you.

Two final comments:

- You should almost certainly not be using the `@techreport` entry type for the entry at hand. The `@techreport` entry type should only be used for pieces issued in working paper series, a discusssion paper series, etc. For the piece at hand, I'd say that either the `@misc` or the `@unpublished` entry type would be appropriate.
- Be sure to load the `xurl` package, so that long URL strings in BibTeX fields can be line-broken without restriction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{scaler_business_2020,
    author      = {{SCALER}},
    title       = {Business case framework},
    HowPublished={\url{https://www.scalerproject.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/D4.3_SCALER_BUSINESS_CASE_FRAMEWORK_v1.0.pdf}},
    Note        = {Accessed: 19.08.2023},
    year        = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks in long URL strings at arbitrary locations
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citet{scaler_business_2020}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, that fixed my problem.